# "Page not found" after importing posts to Wordpress using mysql LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, load-data-infile

I have successfully imported 310,000 posts to the table `wp_posts` using LOAD DATA INFILE (any php based scripts/wp-plugins timed out so I had to use a MySQL only option).

My problem is that although the posts appear fine in wp-admin, they are not accessible by the front-end, "page not found".

Manually 'updating/saving' a post allows it to be accessed from the front-end. Obviously I cant do this with 310,000 posts.

Things I have tried: -

- Saving permalinks without changes
- Saving permalinks with changes
- Disabled all plugins and reenabled them on at a time
- Manually updating .htaccess
- Adding postmeta (entering the same data from an updated working post) for a few posts to see if Wordpress was relying on any of this meta.
- Comparing an updated post row with an untouched post row in `wp_posts` to see if there are any differences (there are not)

I should mention that I am using WooCommerce (so posts are "post_type=product" and all meta added was for WooCommerce) but I strongly believe the issue to be with Wordpress rather than WooCommerce (unless you can tell me otherwise!)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you have access to the DB I'd suggest you examine what changes after saving a page. Eg: compare the before and after state. Then you should be able to run a simple script to automate those changes. Maybe it is something to do with the publish date, or some other metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Phill Healey set me on the right path to answer my own question.

For anyone that come across this in future...

I exported my sql files for the table `wp_posts` and then saved a post, exported a new version of the table and then diff'd them using a text editor (that took ages). This then exposed what my issue was...

My issue lay with there being `\r` characters within my fields. I vaguely remember something setting the LOAD DATA INFILE which type of line-end to use and I didn't know which option to choose so went with (I think) new carriage. And I think that's what buggared me.

I did a not-so-handsome and probably naughty replace of all the `\r` characters and can now access all my posts!!